# This API is not accessible for external HTTP caller

Tags: postman, google-chat-api

Attempting to call google chat API in Postman on the developer's computer, we get the following response.

> {
> "error": {
> "code": 403,
> "message": "This API is not accessible for external HTTP caller.",
> "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
> }
> }

We have authenticated using OAuth2 (apiKey/secret) with scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.messages`.
We did like to use Postman to try out this API.

Is it possible to get around this error? If so, how?